# Handling mouse wheel and keyboard events while a mouse button is pressed

Tags: c#, winforms, mouseevent, keyboard-events

I have a custom WinForms control (derived from Control) in which I override OnMouseXXX and OnKeyXXX events.

I want to handle wheel and/or keyboard events **while** the mouse button is pressed (i.e. OnMouseDown was fired, but OnMouseUp wasn't fired yet). For some reason, I cannot get any of these until I release the mouse button.

Please advise on this matter. Using interop/unsafe code (if needed) would be OK, using a timer to read the keyboard state is not.

Comment: There is no identifiable event to handle a mousewheel event while dragging/pressing the mouse button.
check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820095/can-the-mouse-wheel-be-used-while-dragging-dropping

Comment: Looks exactly like what I needed, I'll try it out, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a global hook, you can go one level up and use IMessageFilter() instead.  This will work for when your application is focused only.  Not sure what level you need to work at...

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{

    private MyFilter filter;

    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        filter = new MyFilter();
        filter.LButtonScroll += new MyFilter.LBUTTONSCROLLDELEGATE(filter_LButtonScroll);
        Application.AddMessageFilter(filter);
    }

    private void filter_LButtonScroll()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("WM_MOUSEWHEEL while LBUTTONDOWN");
    }

    private class MyFilter : IMessageFilter
    {
        private bool LBUTTONDOWN = false;
        private const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x201;
        private const int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x202;
        private const int WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x20a;

        public delegate void LBUTTONSCROLLDELEGATE();
        public event LBUTTONSCROLLDELEGATE LButtonScroll;

        public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
        {
            switch (m.Msg)
            {
                case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
                    LBUTTONDOWN = true;
                    break;

                case WM_MOUSEWHEEL:
                    if (LBUTTONDOWN)
                    {
                        if (LButtonScroll != null)
                        {
                            LButtonScroll();
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                case WM_LBUTTONUP:
                    LBUTTONDOWN = false;
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, works like a charm! While hooks are OK too and both methods are applicable to my situation, I must admit this one is easier. Thank you!

Comment: Both approaches are sledgehammer solutions...I don't think there is a cleaner way though.

Comment: I agree, but in my experience many more or less non-standard features require this kind of code. Which is acceptable, yet regrettable. Also, turned out this approach doesn't work with drag-n-drop, so I might check the hooks out too to see if they'll work with it. But this is beyond the initial question, so this answer stands selected :)